# Why an OS has same name on different achitectures?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, linux-kernel

What is the similarity in running a same OS (like Linux) on different architectures? I mean, we cannot run Linux x86 apps on Linux ARM. And even the OS itself is constructed differently for different architectures. The underlying functionalities are different. They are completely incompatible, except for the GUI. Then why not call it a whole different thing?

Comment: It's for convenience, mate. Don't fuss over it. It's like buttered crackers and salted crackers. In the end, they're both crackers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but if you take for example debian on X86 or ARM it will work the same. The binaries are not compatible because the CPU architecture is not the same and everything had to be recompiled. When you are only using OSS this will be no problem most of the time (unless the code uses X86 assembler and you want to compile it for ARM, for example).

I think what you refer to is that some devices running linux don't work the same as a linux-distro (debian, fedora, ...). That is because they're not a normal linux-distro, but special builds for that certain device.
Linux as such, is only a kernel and you are free to build any user-land environment around it and that is how they can be different.